# How to use TYPEs in Telegram Bot API?

Tags: php, curl, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm new to Telegram Bot. I know how to use METHODs to send a message or others by file_get_contents method in PHP or cURL, But I don't know enough about TYPEs. Although I read in Telegram Page, It was very misunderstood. So I don't know how to use TYPEs in my Bot. I want to create a Keyboard for my Bot, So I think when I use cURL, I should send TYPEs with parameters. So I wrote the code below :

```
$Params = array (
    'chat_id' => $ChatID,
    'text' => 'Hello !',
    'ReplyKeyboardMarkup' => array (
        'keyboard' =>  array(array('Hello', 'Hi'))
    )
);
```

It sends me message when I use the cURL :

```
$Curl = curl_init("https://api.telegram.org/bot".$APIToken."/sendMessage");
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($Params));
curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($Curl);
curl_close($Curl);
```

But It doesn't show me the Keyboards ..., What is my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the key `reply_markup` with the format of the [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup)

```
$ReplyKeyboardMarkup = array(
    "keyboard" => array(
        array("1st row left", "1st row right"), 
        array("2nd row left", "2nd row right")
    )
);

$Params = array (
    'chat_id' => $ChatID,
    'text' => 'Hello !',
    'reply_markup' => json_encode($ReplyKeyboardMarkup)
);
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks my friend ..., I know about ReplyKeyboard Parameters like Resizing or ..., But I don't know how can I declare Keyboard for Location or Phone ..., Can you give me example for it too ?

Comment: Simply replace the button text with another array in the format of a KeyboardButton:  `array("text" => "Send Location", "request_location" => true)`